# Can a reference refer to more than one object during its lifetime?

Tags: c++

As I know a reference can refer to only one object during its lifetime..
However,the code bellow compiles correctly.. although I have changed the referred object.. The output is:1.
How can it compile correctly?

Thanks
Shiran

```
class A{
 private:
int a;
 public:
A(int a):a(a){}
virtual ~A(){}
virtual void f()const {cout<<a<<endl;}
};
class B: public A{
 private:
int b;
 public:
B(int Ina,int Inb):A(Ina),b(Inb){}
virtual void f()const {cout<<b<<endl;}
};

int main(){
    B b(1,2);
    A a(5);
    A& ref=a;
    ref=b;
    ref.f();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The right way to think about it is that a reference *is* the object it references. Therefore, if you do:

```
A& ref = a;
ref = b;
```

Since `ref` *is* `a`, what you're doing is:

```
a = b;
```

Answer (score 1):

A reference refers only one referrant during its entire lifetime.
What your code does is assigns the new value to the original refferant.

Answer (score 0):

Your main function is equivalent to this:

```
B b(1,2);
A a(5);
a = b;
a.f();
```

Assigning to a reference is equivalent to assigning to the original object.